# Only display entries based on a field conditional

Tags: entry, sections, conditional, forloop, limit

Hey I am trying to get 4 entries, but only want 4 that have a body length > 100.

How would I accomplish this?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').order('RAND()').limit(4) %}
  // only display 4 entries with entry.body|length > 100
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend to use the fantastic [Preparse](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) plugin to save to length of your body text in a hidden field.

Create and add a new "bodyLength" Preparse field to your "Artists" entry type. Use this Twig code in the field settings:

```
{{ entry.body|length }}
```

To update all existing entries, re-save them by going into Settings → Sections → Artists and click Save.
You can now simply set up a criteria model to query for entries with a body length greater than 100 like so:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('artists').bodyLength('> 100') %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
{# Grab all entries with a body > 100 %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').order('RAND()').find() if entry.body|length > 100 %}

{# Limit output to the first 4 #}
{% if loop.index1 <= 4 %}
        {{ entry.id }}'s body field has a length greater than 100!<br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that if `entry.body` is a [Rich Text field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields) than any HTML markup (`<p>`, `<span>`, etc.) will be included in that length count as well.

Twig doesn't have a `break` or `continue` tag natively, but if you install the [MN Break and Continue plugin](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/mn-break-and-continue), you can make it a bit more efficient:

```
{# Grab all entries with a body > 100 %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('artists').order('RAND()').find() if entry.body|length > 100 %}
    {% if loop.index1 > 4 %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ entry.id }}'s body field has a length greater than 100!<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Brad. 

using this code runs through the 4 entries and only displaying the ones that have `body|length > 100`. So sometime this will only display two entries since the other two has `body|length < 100`. What I am trying to achieve is to always show 4 entries.

Comment: Ahh, updated answer.